# How to write awk command to group line data and dump to file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, data-processing

One data file consists of multiple line data. A quick look of data file is like:

```
./gc_string/datadata.distr  10  1273377106  2
./gc_string/datadata.distr  10  -540812264  2
./gc_string/datadata.distr  10  318171673  2
./app_fib/datadata.distr  4  -1593911137  3
./app_fib/datadata.distr  4  -1345649758  3
./app_fib/datadata.distr  5  -1545930833  3
./app_fib/datadata.distr  5  1916879527  3
./app_fib/datadata.distr  5  609112984  3
./app_fib/datadata.distr  6  111417553  3
./app_fib/datadata.distr  6  -1545460791  3
.........
```

What i want to do is group line datas and write them to each different files according to 1st column. The rule is all columns except 1st column are written to the same file if 1st have same value. The file name is based on 1st column value. For example, two files will generated with above data:

```
gc_string.txt
-------------------
10  1273377106  2
10  -540812264  2
10  318171673  2

app_fib.txt
-------------------
4  -1593911137  3
4  -1345649758  3
5  -1545930833  3
5  1916879527  3
..
```

I think the bash awk can perform this task. I tried several ways but fail.  Could anyone give me tips? 
Thanks

Comment: I don't see any difficulties to do that by awk, if you spend 10 minutes to read awk guide. Can you show us what you do for this question first? Hints, check the usage on how to do with print command and how to set proper FS by awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{split($1,a,"/"); print $2,$3,$4 > a[2] ".txt"}' datafile
```

Comment: +1 but you should always parenthesize expressions on the right side of output redirection (`>`) as otherwise it's ambiguous and different awks will interpret it differently. In this case `print $2,$3,$4 > a[2] ".txt"` should be written instead as `print $2,$3,$4 > (a[2] ".txt")` so it's not interpreted as `(print $2,$3,$4 > a[2]) ".txt"`.